# What does the dot mean at the end of `-rw-r--r--`? How do you set it with `chmod`?

Tags: linux, permissions, shell, selinux

Some of the files in my directories under Linux have a `.` at the end of the permissions listing.

- What does the dot mean at the end of `-rw-r--r--`?
- How do you set it with `chmod`?

Answer (score 124):

According to [`ls.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?id=v8.21#n3785) (line 3785), `.` means an [SELinux ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). (`+` means a [general ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list#Filesystem_ACLs).)

Answer (score 46):

I had the same question.  It took me a while to find this, having browsed the "man ls" page a hundred times (well, maybe not that often) until I finally saw the note in the SEE ALSO section about using the command:

```
 info coreutils 'ls invocation'
```

In the section describing "-l" (--format=long):

```
 Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
 whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
 applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
 bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is
 a printing character, then there is such a method.

 GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
 security context, but no other alternate access method.

 A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
 marked with a `+' character.
```

Answer (score 15):

This is SELinux context. Try `ls -Z /your/file`

Quoting my `man ls`

> ```
>    SELinux options:
>
>    --lcontext
>           Display security context.   Enable -l. Lines will probably be too wide for most displays.
>
>    -Z, --context
>           Display security context so it fits on most displays.  Displays only mode, user, group, security context and file name.
>
>    --scontext
>           Display only security context and file name.
> ```

To change this, try one of these commands: `chcon` or `semanage fcontext` or `restorecon`

Quite neatly explained here:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files.html

Answer (score 11):

It means the file has an access list with SELinux. Check out this topic, it tells you how to allow you to edit/change the file http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1315684

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is due to an Access Control List [**(ACL)**](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) although I've only seen them shown as a `+` as in `rw-rw-rw-+`.  Perhaps the `.` means a lack of an ACL on that file.

You can try typing `getfacl .` in the current directory to see what access controls those files might have.

Comment: Nope, the dot doesn't mean lack of ACLs - see other answers