# Permissions to use the files of other users

Tags: linux, permissions, user-accounts

I have a plugin that must read some files every X minutes (this plugin is running under user1), those files belong to user2 (from another application), the structure is something like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user2 5536 4096 sep  2 11:09 directory1
#Inside this directory, it contains some files:
-rw-r--r--. 1 user2 5536  0 mar 10  2020 file1
-rw-r--r--. 1 user2 5536  0 mar  8  2018 file2
```

When I run the plugin, it does not let me access these files, it is returning this error:

```
check your filesystem (permissions/usage/integrity) and disk devices
```

Changing the owner of the directory and the files is not an option (because those files are used by another application).

I also tried to change the permissions of those files to 777 but it returns the same error.

**EDIT:** Creating a group and including both users is not an option, because it could generate problems with one of the applications.

Comment: Relevant: [What does the dot mean at the end of `-rw-r--r--`?](https://superuser.com/q/230559/432690)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski so I must include that user into the selinux ACL? First I tough about Selinux, but it is running in permissive

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you more with this. If I knew SELinux, I would have written a proper answer already. Hopefully somebody else will. Good luck.